# loading fileS into a field of a BLOB type. PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, blob

The task is:

> Load all files from a specified directory into a table, into a field
>   of a BLOB type

What confuses me is that all files are to be written into **one** BLOB field.

Is it possible to do in a meaningful way, so that we could read separate files from the BLOB field later?

What comes to my mind is to use some sort of a separator character between each file when writing to a blob.

Little help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427695/reading-multiple-values-from-a-blob-field-pl-sql

Answer (score 0):

One way can be to save each file in separate blob, each in it's own line (having same DIRECTORY_ID): 

`M_DIRECTORY      FILE_NAME FILE_CONTENT(blob) 

1                abc.txt   [content of the file] 

1                a.zip     [content of the file]` 


 
Another option if you are really really sure you will never change data, you can store it in one BLOB, zipped content of this directory.  
 
If have a doubt, choose 1st option.

Comment: I've been told that there is a function that puts some sort of a separator between files when you write them into the same BLOB file,